# Deploying web application on glassfish server without internet access

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

My web application has a glassfish-web.xml configuration file. It references a DTD on glassfish.org, but I don't have internet access, so everytime I try to deploy, I get an error saying that it is unable to locate the DTD(obviously, since I have no internet access). I tried to just put a "" in the place of the DTD URL String, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Comment: Get internet access? :P

Comment: Nice :-) Why didn't I think of that

Comment: On a serious note, I would think that this is something that companies who deploy to servers on an internal/closed network would encounter all the time, no? Maybe they have a local copy of the DTD that they point to?

Comment: Perhaps, but then the url would refer to the local version and could potentially be useless when deployed (unless there was some sort of macro system in place that could determine the location based on where it was deployed to).  I guess in the world of internet development, the connection is seen as a prerequisite.

Comment: You should include the offending DOCTYPE element of your `glassfish-web.xml`. This shouldn't be an issue and I'm guessing there is something wrong with your xml. Check out [this thread](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/unable-locate-dtd-validate-your-deployment-descriptor-file-web-infglassfish-webxml-archive]).

Comment: Also [this thread](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/how-disable-fetch-remote-dtds-during-deployment)

Comment: Maybe you can add the exception and your `glassfish-web.xml` to the question.